# changing textbox color bootstrap from white to Gray

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to chnage to default textbox color white of bootstrap to gray, like this:

```
  textarea{
        color:gray;
    }
```

But that doesnt work.

Thank you

I triied that, like this:

```
textarea{
    background-color:gray;
}
```

and this is for example a textbox:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">

                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-2" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 250px;" })
            </div>

</form>
```

But the texbox stays white.

Comment: white `color` or `background-color`?

Comment: "color:" is used for the textarea text and the "background-color:" is used for the textarea background color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
textarea{ 
    background-color:gray !important;
}
```

For textbox

```
input[type="text"]{
background-color:gray !important
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that is it. And for texbox? I try: 
textbox{

    background-color:gray !important;
}

Comment: Who put my question to -1???? I am not clear??

Comment: try this for input text input[type="text"] { background-color:gray !important }

Comment: I do not know who put -1

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) instead:

```
textarea{
    background-color:gray;
}
```